# 1950s short story where natives of an alien planet "help" humans solve problems, with each solution creating a bigger problem

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

This story was in a 1950s anthology of classic sci-fi stories. The aliens are friendly, and recommend planting a certain hedge, I think, to solve a problem. When the hedge becomes a problem, they recommend a solution that in turn creates a bigger problem, until ultimately the humans find the planet uninhabitable. (Lessons there about tinkering with the environment.)

Comment: Hm.  See if anything here rings a bell. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ApocalypseHow

Comment: Sounds like something from Robert Sheckley and the timing works out. I can't remember the particular story though.